# Validate uniqueness based on custom business logic in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am working on a task in which I have to implement database-level constraints for some business logic (which I understand shouldn't be the way to go, but I have to follow this approach).

The database in question is Oracle 10g.

I have a table called Entry and a join table called Entry_Department that contain the following columns, all varchars:

Entry:

- ID
- Name
- Type
- User_ID (nullable)

Entry_Department:

- Entry_ID (foreign key to Entry.ID)
- Department_ID (foreign key to a field in Department table, which I don't think will be necessary to describe in this context)

The current valid Types are "UserEntry" and "DepartmentEntry". Below are the expected validation rules:

- Entries that are not of type UserEntry cannot have the same name; in other words, every Entry that isn't a UserEntry must have a unique name.
- If it is a UserEntry, the name of the entry can be the same as long as the User_ID is also unique.
- A UserEntry cannot share the same name as another Entry that is not a UserEntry.
- Entry_Department.Entry_ID should not reference an Entry.ID of which type is not DepartmentEntry.

How can I implement this validation on the database level?

Answer (score 1):

The first two requirements are on columns in the same table.  They can be enforced with a unique function-based index.

**Sample Schema**

```
create table entry
(
    id number primary key,
    name varchar2(100) not null,
    type varchar2(100) not null,
    user_id number
);

create table entry_department
(
    id number primary key,
    entry_id number references entry(id),
    department_id number not null
);
```

**Index for the First Two Rules**

```
create unique index entry_uk1 on entry(
    case when type <> 'UserEntry' then name else name||'|'||user_id end);

--Not UserEntry, cannot have the same name.
--The second insert fails with:
--ORA-00001: unique constraint (JHELLER.ENTRY_UK1) violated
insert into entry values(1, 'A', 'type1', 1);
insert into entry values(2, 'A', 'type1', 2);

--UserEntry, the name can be same.  These work.
insert into entry values(3, 'A', 'UserEntry', 3);
insert into entry values(4, 'A', 'UserEntry', 4);

--But if NAME and USER_ID are not unique, this fails with:
--ORA-00001: unique constraint (JHELLER.ENTRY_UK1) violated
insert into entry values(5, 'A', 'UserEntry', 4);
```

**Fourth Rule**

The third requirement is more difficult as it spans multiple tables.  There are a few ways to do this - triggers, referential integrity based on a virtual column, and materialized views.

The trigger method requires a lot of code to get right and in my experience is never done correctly.  Virtual columns are an 11g feature and are not available.  (But it's time to have a talk with your DBAs - 10g is getting pretty old now.  Even 11g is almost out of premier support.)

I prefer to use materialized views to enforce multi-table constraints.  Create a materialized view that returns rows that should never exist, and then create a constraint on the materialized view that fails if any rows are generated.

```
--Create materialized view logs, so that relevant columns are tracked.
create materialized view log on entry with rowid(id, name, type);
create materialized view log on entry_department with rowid(entry_id);

--Create a SELECT statement that should never be true.
--Fast refresh materialized views are picky.
--For example, they must use the old-fashioned join syntax, and in this case
--must return ROWIDs from both tables.
create materialized view entry_department_wrong_type_mv
build immediate
refresh fast on commit as
select 1 should_not_exist, entry.rowid e_rowid, entry_department.rowid ed_rowid
from entry, entry_department
where entry.id = entry_department.entry_id
    and entry.type <> 'DepartmentEntry';

--Create constraint to make sure that the materialized view never has any rows.
alter materialized view entry_department_wrong_type_mv
add constraint entry_deparment_wrong_type_ck check (should_not_exist <> 1);

--Works fine:
insert into entry values(1, 'A', 'DepartmentEntry', 1);
insert into entry_department values (1, 1, 1);
commit;

--The COMMIT fails with this error:
--ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
--ORA-02290: check constraint (JHELLER.ENTRY_DEPARMENT_WRONG_TYPE_CK) violated
insert into entry values(2, 'B', 'Wrong Type!', 2);
insert into entry_department values (2, 2, 2);
commit;
```

**Third Rule**

```
--A UserEntry cannot share the same name as another Entry that is not a UserEntry.
create materialized view entry_ue_not_ue_sharing_mv
build immediate
refresh fast on commit as
select 1 should_not_exist, e1.rowid e1_rowid, e2.rowid e2_rowid
from entry e1, entry e2
where e1.name = e2.name
    and e1.type = 'UserEntry'
    and e2.type <> 'UserEntry';


--Create constraint to make sure that the materialized view never has any rows.
alter materialized view entry_ue_not_ue_sharing_mv
add constraint entry_ue_not_ue_sharing_ck check (should_not_exist <> 1);

--COMMIT fails with:
--ORA-12048: error encountered while refreshing materialized view "JHELLER"."ENTRY_UE_NOT_UE_SHARING_MV"
--ORA-02290: check constraint (JHELLER.ENTRY_UE_NOT_UE_SHARING_CK) violated
insert into entry values(10, 'Same Name 1', 'Not UserEntry', 1);
insert into entry values(11, 'Same Name 1', 'UserEntry', 2);
commit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Unfortunately, it seems my description of the first two validation rules was unclear, my apologies - the catch is that if there is an existing Entry that is not a UserEntry with a certain name, another UserEntry cannot share that name. So for example, if we have an Entry of type 'Type1' and name 'EntryA', then try to create a UserEntry with name 'EntryA', that should fail.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a row-based trigger to be invoked before inserts allowed me to validate the data as required.

Unfortunately, I am unable to post the exact code due to an NDA, but the general logic was to get a count of rows that had the same Entry name if it was not a UserEntry, or if was a UserEntry, to get a count of rows that had the same Entry name and either the same User_ID or a type not equivalent to UserEntry.

Comment: Using only before-triggers wouldn't prevent two concurrent sessions from violating the rules.  If there's a lot of activity on this database you have to be very careful with triggers.

Comment: Interesting mention - do you have any references or scenarios to share that illustrate this issue?

Comment: Tom Kyte has a few bad things to say about triggers [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3868442800346504246).  That post is actually promoting a tool that uses triggers, but only because the author is an expert and has done it right.  One quote from the article: "The problem I have with triggers is that many (i would say most, the vast majority) people that write them do not understand how they will work in a multi-user environment."  To be safe, create a few loops that insert/update/delete at the same time, see if the rules can be broken.